# Trying to use skimage.morphology in an image processing code but get error message

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working thru an image processing example in python 2.7.13. The code has
`import skimage.morphology as morph` and then later has the line `lm1 = morph.is_local_maximum(fimg)`. I get the error message:

```
File "2dlocalmaxima.py", line 29, in <module>
    lm1 = morph.is_local_maximum(fimg)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'is_local_maximum'.
```

I've googled this and have found many instances of this module being used. I can find no instance of this being deprecated. Am I doing something wrong? I have tried running in python 2.7.13 and 3.6. Both give same error message.

The total code from the book is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl 
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage 
import skimage.morphology as morph

# Generating data points with a non-uniform background
x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=200, size=20).astype(int) 
y = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=400, size=20).astype(int)

# Creating image with non-uniform background 
func = lambda x, y: np.cos(x)+ np.sin(y) 
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:12:200j, 0:24:400j] 
bkg = func(grid_x, grid_y)
bkg = bkg / np.max(bkg)

# Creating points
clean = np.zeros((200,400))
clean[(x,y)] += 5
clean = ndimage.gaussian_filter(clean, 3) 
clean = clean / np.max(clean)

# Combining both the non-uniform background 
# and points
fimg = bkg + clean
fimg = fimg / np.max(fimg)

# Calculating local maxima 
lm1 = morph.is_local_maximum(fimg)
x1, y1 = np.where(lm1.T == True)

# Creating figure to show local maximum detection 
# rate success
fig = mpl.figure(figsize=(8, 4))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(fimg)
ax.scatter(x1, y1, s=100, facecolor='none', edgecolor='#009999') 
ax.set_xlim(0,400)
ax.set_ylim(0,200)
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

fig.savefig('scikit_image_f02.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: What version of SciKit-Image are you using?

Comment: how do i tell which version?

Comment: I ran 'pip install scikit-image'  it ran to completion but results are the same. I couldn't tell which version though.

Comment: Check `skimage.__version__`. It's a common convention for Python packages to make their version number accessible as the root module's `__version__` attribute like this.

Comment: best I can tell its version 0.13.0  if this seems correct.  I did a 'conda list' command and thats what I got.

Comment: It looks as if 'is_local_maximum' should be 'local_maxima'. or initial guess that seems to work.  Thanks for your help.  Looking for version number led me to some files which provided clues.

Comment: If you've figured out the problem, I'd definitely encourage you to post an answer to your own question (and you can accept it, too).

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching thru different files I determined that the module `is_local_maximum` had its name changed to `local_maxima`. My code ran to completion and produced the expected result when that substitution was made.